# How to get an AWS ServiceLinkedRole ARN in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a CloudFormation stack for AWS Config service using ServiceLinkedRole for Config, however I have no idea how to refer to ARN of created AWS Config role in the same CloudFormation template, this is the config snippet:

```
  AWSServiceLinkedRoleForConfig:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ServiceLinkedRole'
    Properties:
      AWSServiceName: config.amazonaws.com
      Description: AWS Config Service Linked role
  ConfigRecorder: 
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigurationRecorder
    Properties: 
      Name: AWSConfigForTest
      RecordingGroup: 
        ResourceTypes: 
          - "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
      RoleARN: ??
```

I've tried below formats:

```
RoleARN: !Ref "AWSServiceLinkedRoleForConfig"
```

> The role arn passed 'AWSServiceRoleForConfig' is not valid. (Service:
>   AmazonConfig; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRoleException;
>   )

```
RoleARN: !Ref "AWSServiceLinkedRoleForConfig.Arn"
```

> Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies
>   [AWSServiceLinkedRoleForConfig.Arn] in the Resources block of the
>   template

According to the below cheatsheet there are no outputs ARN for ServiceLinkedRole resource:
https://theburningmonk.com/cloudformation-ref-and-getatt-cheatsheet/

If this is the case how can I refer to ARN for this role in CloudFormation template file?

Answer (score 6):

I just got an answer from AWS:

> there is no way to directly reference the ARN of a service linked role
>   created in CloudFormation

Available workaround:

RoleARN:
    !Join
      - ''
      - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
        - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
        - ':role/aws-service-role/config.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForConfig'

Answer (score 1):

In your CloudFormation `Resources`, create the role and in the `Properties` section, give it a `RoleName`:

```
  MyRoleForCodePipeline:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: myrolename
      ...
```

Then create the pipeline and manually build the ARN using your account id (e.g., 123456780) and the role name from above:

```
  MyCodePipeline:
    Type:  AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: mycodepipelinename
      RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::123456780:role/myrolename'
      ...
```